# Using compareTo to compare strings of numbers isn't working as planned, how do i fix this?

Tags: java, android, string

[image: The app itself running to show my issue]

So i am trying to get it so that it orders this list from highest value to lowest value by using the 2nd column of the 2d string array.

By looking online the answer seemed to be simple all i had to do was make my own comparator.

Which looks like this in the code

```
        Arrays.sort(stockPriceAndNameSorted, new Comparator<String[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(final String[] entry1, final String[] entry2) {
            return entry1[1].compareTo(entry2[1]);
        }
    });
```

But as you can see it is not being ordered as it should, if for example i give it the values, 1,2,3,4,5 it works fine. Change that to 1,11,3,4,5 however and it doesn't work as it should.

Comment: It is sorted in alphabetical order, which makes sense for a String. You should use a number instead of a string for what you want...

Comment: But you cannot have a 2d array with a String and an int in java, without using an object which you cannot sort.

Comment: then create a class encapsulating the string and the int...

Comment: The reason for this malfunction is that your comparator compares strings. Strings are compared char by char startting with the first. Consider strings "11" and "2". The first char compared: '1' < '2' thus "11" < "2". Solution is to parse the strings before comparison so that they are compared as numbers (thus 2 < 11).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You compared the `String` values, which results in a different order than numeric order.  Compare the integer values instead:

```
Arrays.sort(stockPriceAndNameSorted, new Comparator<String[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final String[] entry1, final String[] entry2) {
        return Integer.valueOf(entry1[1]).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(entry2[1]));
    }
});
```

You may want to substitute another numeric class for `Integer` if, for example, you have numbers with decimal points in your strings.  Also, you may want to handle the `NumberFormatException` that may occur if the string value isn't able to be parsed as a number.

Comment: Yes it works, thanks ever so much. I did go down the route of trying to convert it into ints but i wasn't quite sure how.

Answer (score 0):

It is sorted in alphabetical order, which makes sense for a String. You should use a number instead of a string for what you want.

Alternatively, you can do:

```
int price1 = Integer.parseInt(entry1[1]);
int price2 = Integer.parseInt(entry2[1]);
return Integer.compare(price1, price2);
```

But that feels a bit ugly to be honest.

A better way would be (I am ommitting getters etc.):

```
class Item {
    String name;
    int price;
}

Item[] items = ...; //or use an ArrayList
Arrays.sort((stockPriceAndNameSorted, new Comparator<String[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final Item entry1, final Item entry2) {
        return Integer.compare(entry1.price, entry2.price);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'll keep this in mind for next time. I had to use a string though as it is part of a 2d array, and you can't do sorts with objects in java i believe.

Thankfully @rgettman has the answer for me.

Comment: So i tried this method, but when i got to the array.sort it is now throwing up a bunch of errors.

And would i now not be trying to sort the Item class itself rather than the stockPriceAndNameSorted array?